# how push and Shift are used together in this code?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I was looking at the merge sort code and I don't understand how we push and shift together, if that is not  what happening there can some tell me

```
 result.push(node1[0] < node2[0]? node1.shift() : node2.shift());
```

```
function mergeSort (arr) {
    if (arr.length < 2) {
      return arr;
    }

    var mid = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);
    var subLeft = mergeSort(arr.slice(0, mid));
    var subRight = mergeSort(arr.slice(mid));

    return merge(subLeft, subRight);
}

function merge (node1, node2) {
    var result = [];
    while (node1.length > 0 && node2.length > 0)
        result.push(node1[0] < node2[0]? node1.shift() : node2.shift());
    return result.concat(node1.length? node1 : node2);
}
``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shift() method removes the first element from an array and returns that removed element. This method changes the length of the array.

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var firstElement = array1.shift();

console.log(array1);
// expected output: Array [2, 3]

console.log(firstElement);
// expected output: 1
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)